# Rails: Aggregate queries through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In rails, is there an ActiveRecord way of doing an aggregate query through a `has_many :through` association?

*EDIT: I'm looking for a database-driven solution, not a bunch of Ruby iterating/munging.*

*EDIT #2: I screwed this up. The Venue model is also many-to-many with Show.*

For instance. Imagine something (contrived) like this:

```
# Venue<->Show is many-to-many.
# Show<->Performer is many-to-many.

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :shows, through: :bookings
end

# Note "show" here would be "The Lion King," not a specific
# performance on a specific date.
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :venues, through: :bookings

  has_many :engagements
  has_many :performers, through: :engagements
end

class Performer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :engagements
  has_many :shows, through: :engagements
end

# Just a simple join model.
class Engagement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :performer
end

# Also a join model.
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :show
end
```

How might one perform a query on `Venue` which returns a unique set of all `Performer`s that have ever performed there?

Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion the most simple way would be to execute sql since you are looking for performance. A major reason a lot a people chose rails is because a quicker work cycle not the frameworks performance. There are a [lot of higher throughput frameworks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/). When you start to spend a great deal of time on optimization it kind of kill the joy of ruby.

Comment: Antarr, I totally understand that, but there's a big difference between "Ruby and Rails aren't all that fast" and "this way of querying the DB is literally 10,000x slower than this other way". If raw SQL is the only way, so be it (sadface). Thanks for weighing in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a collection of Performers at the end, start with that model. We know we're looking for a specific Venue, so let's see which associations we can use to get there.

```
# Performer
has_many :shows, through: :engagements

# Show
has_many :venues, through: :bookings
```

Bingo! We can go from Performers to Shows to Venues (Rails will figure out the joins from Engagements to Shows and Bookings to Venues automatically).

ActiveRecord supports joining on associations using the association name (Note: this only works for INNER joins): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations

After reading that querying guide, we know we can join on nested associations using a Hash syntax. That gets us to

```
Performer.joins(shows: :venues)
```

But we can't stop there because then we'll get all Performers that have played at least one Show at at least one Venue (with duplicates of any Performers in more than one Show, Engagement, Booking or Venue—we'll deal with these momentarily). In order to narrow the collection down, we have to add a WHERE clause. Section 12.3 of the linked guide explains that we can add Hash conditions to joined tables.
Narrowing down the venue looks like

```
venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
Performer.joins(shows: :venues).where(venues: {id: venue.id})
```

Now we have all Performers that have played in all Shows at this Venue! But wait, we still have duplicate Performers if they've played in more than one Show (or Engagement). In order to remove the duplicates, we use `uniq`.

Putting it all together gives us

```
venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
Performer.joins(shows: :venues).where(venues: {id: venue.id}).uniq
```

Comment: This does indeed work. Thanks! Can you edit your answer to explain a bit about ***why*** it works and what's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
venue = Venue.find(?)

# Select only unique Performer ids
unique_performer_ids = Performer.joins(:engagements).where(show_id: venue.show_id).distinct(:id)

# Select unique Performer objects
performers = Performer.where(id: unique_performer_ids)
```

Possible to union these two queries to one use sub-queries.